# Querying many-to-many relationship: get all products with tag by name

Tags: javascript, many-to-many, relationship, loopbackjs

This should actually be pretty easy to do, but I have not managed....

Let's say we have a model `Product`. A `Product` can have multiple `Tag`. The relationship is defined like this:

`common/models/product.json`

```
{
  "name": "Product",
  #other stuff
  "relations": {
      "tags": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Tag",
      "foreignKey": "productId",
      "through": "ProductTags"
    }
  },
  #more stuff
}
```

`common/models/product-tags.json`

```
{
  "name": "ProductTags",
  #more stuff
  "relations": {
    "product": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Product",
      "foreignKey": "productId"
    },  
    "tag": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Tag",
      "foreignKey": "tagId"
    }   
  },  
  #more stuff
}
```

`common/models/tag.json`

```
  {
      "name": "Tag",
      #more stuff
       "properties": {
         "name": {
         "type": "string",
         "required": true,
         "index": {
         "unique": true
       }
      },
      "relations": {
        "pictures": {
          "type": "hasMany",
          "model": "Pictures",
          "foreignKey": "tagId",
          "through": "PictureTags"
        }
        "products": {
          "type": "hasMany",
          "model": "Product",
          "foreignKey": "tagId",
          "through": "ProductTags"
        }
      },
      #more stuff
    }
```

How do I query for all products by tag name? E.g. get all products which have a tag name "XYZ" (if we could use "like", even better, so that the query is not on exact match, but on a "like"). REST query format preferred.

I've tried looking at:
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter
But my include filter would first return all products,and add tags information for them.

EDIT:
A few tries:

```
curl --globoff http://localhost:3000/api/v1/Tags?filter[where][name][inq]=FirstTag&filter[where][name][inq]=ThirdTag&filter[include][products]
```

This one is straight from the docs 
returns an error:

> The name property has invalid clause {\"inq\":\"FirstTag\"}\

```
curl --globoff http://localhost:3000/api/v1/Products?filter=[include][tags][name]=NonExistingTag
```

which returns all products nonetheless

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/Products?filter[where]tags][name]=First" --globoff
```

returns this error:
    {
      "error": {
        "name": "TypeError",
        "status": 500,
        "message": "Cannot read property 'type' of undefined",
        "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined\n    at PostgreSQL.toColumnValue (/home/fabio/prj/fapl/src/loopback/node_modules/loopback-connector-postgresql/lib/postgresql.js:432:11)\n

Also I looked at:
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter
But couldn't find any relevant example...the where clause is for the products objects themselves, not for a related model.

Comment: Can you share the include filter you tried? Also, what happens if you load a tag and tell it to include products?

Answer (score 1):

If your models are set up correctly you should be able to do something like

```
//...snip...
Tag.findById(tagId, function(err, tag){

  // works for multiple relation types
  // hasMany, hasAndBelongsToMany, etc
  tag.products({}, function(err, productsWithTag) {
    if(err) return cb(err);
    // productsWithTag available here
  });

});
//...snip...
```

Which should return all the products for that tag. `findById` could be replaced with a `find(filter...)` instead to get at the tag instance by name or query.

See https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasAndBelongsToMany+relations at the bottom for "methods added to the model" for guidance. Also check that your model json is correct and figure out if it's `hasAndBelongsToMany` or a combination of `hasMany` and `belongsTo` that works best.

Comment: Basically the same approach as the answer from google groups, only that that one doesn't need custom implementations :)

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question on the loopbackjs google group as well.

Someone (Nuba Princigalli, if you are here you should post your solution as answer, so that I can accept it...) posted this answer:

> Assuming your tags live at /api/tags, just make a HTTP GET request at
>   /api/tags?filter={"where":{"id":"1234"}, "include":"products"}"
>   customizing the where clause to fit your needs with a like or a regex.
>
> If more than one tag is returned, each will have its own list of
>   products. If you want just a single product list, you could merge them
>   on the client, or do the query in two steps: find all tags matching
>   your where filter, including their related ProductTags, then use those
>   to build a list of product ids you'll want, then find all products
>   using the inq operator.
>   https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter#Wherefilter-inq
>   . No custom endpoint needed.

It's somehow not intuitive to have to query tags in order to get products. Also, if a product is assigned multiple tags, and I am querying multiple tags, I would get the same product multiple times.

Not ideal but this is ok for the time being for us!

Comment: If you are going to be exposing an API to external parties, it's better to create a custom remote method to support this instead of essentially writing a SQL WHERE clause in the URI. Would be much cleaner to expose /api/productsWithTag/<tagname> IMO. But if this is all for internal users who will know or have access to the schema anyway, not a huge deal.

Comment: yep sounds reasonable